# /dev/log: Connection refused after boot, but only on one system

Tags: systemd, logs, syslog, rsyslog, systemd-journald

I have two systems running NVIDIA jetpack 5.0.2, based on Ubuntu 20.04.  `/etc` and `/boot` are identical on both systems.  On the first system, after boot, if I try to run `logger` I get an error `/dev/log: Connection refused`.  If I run `systemctl restart systemd-journald-dev-log.socket` then it works fine until the next reboot.  On the second system, `logger` works reliably every time.

I've run `systemd-analyze plot` and there are some differences between the two systems:

- on the first system: `systemd-journald-dev-log.socket` seems to run for only a short time
- on the first system: `rsyslog.service` seems to start much much later, right after `systemd-journald-dev-log.socket` ends
- on the first system: `dev-hugepages.mount` exists

What can I look at to understand the issue?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I have a similar problem with two Raspbian 11 systems that are (intended to be) identical. Obviously they aren't! :)

Comment: yeah we had introduced a service that created a cyclic dependency